# Very similar types in the same list (Inheritance vs Discriminated Unions vs Generics?)

Tags: generics, inheritance, f#, currying, discriminated-union

I'm creating a module with functions, that each take a state specific to the function and produce a float and a state of the same type:

- function `f` works with a state of type `FState`
- function `g` works with a state of type `GState`
- function `h` works with a state of type `HState`
- function `steps` is for evaluating a list of functions, for a list of states in the same order.

**Lib.fs**

```
module Lib

type FState = {y:int; z:string}
let f (x:float) (s:FState) : float * FState = (x+1.0, {s with y=s.y+1})

type GState = {y:string}
let g (x:float) (s:GState) : float * GState = (x*2.0, s)

type HState = {z:float}
let h (s:HState) : float * HState = (0.0, s)

let steps funs (states: 'a list) = List.mapi (fun i f -> f states.[i])
```

I want the user of this module, to be able to:

- "put these functions and states in a list", and evaluate them
- define their own state & function, and "put these in the same list" (such as function `e` with state `EState`, below)

**Program.fs**

```
open Lib

type EState = {y:float}
let e (s:EState) : float * EState = (1.0, {s with y=s.y/2.0})

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let funs : (? -> float * ?) list =
        [ f 0.0
        ; f 1.0
        ; g 5.0
        ; h
        ; e
        ]

    let states : ? list =
        [ {FState.y=1; z=""}
        ; {FState.y=1; z=""}
        ; {GState.y=""}
        ; {HState.z=2.0}
        ; {EState.y=4.0}
        ]

    let results : (float * ?) list = steps funs states
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

I naively put a question mark `?`, where i don't know what the common type should be.

**Thoughts**

I'm thinking, that i might be able to create common types with Inheritance or a Discriminated Union.

- But with a Discriminated Union, the user might not be able to extend the common type
- On the other hand, I expect that this has been done before in Functional Programming without requiring inheritance

Either way i don't even know if this is even feasible.

**Question**

I would prefer to keep everything statically type checked.

- How would you solve this?

**Extra context**

The functions are actually calculating the value for the next point of a line on the same graph (that's why I'm trying to put them in the same list). Depending on the line being drawn, each function needs to keep track of different state information. In actual current code, some functions produce the point for more than 1 line to avoid repeating calculations (although that may be a design flaw on my part)

**Attempt at `steps` with Generics** (doesn't compile)

```
let step (f: 'a -> float * 'a) (s:'b) = f (s :?> 'a)
let steps funs (states: 'a list) = List.mapi (fun i f -> step f states.[i])
```

Comment: **Question 1:** how would you do this in any other language you know? If that language happens to be dynamically typed, then **Question 1a:** how would you do this in any statically typed language? **Question 2:** what would you like to happen when `funs` doesn't match `states`?

Comment: Oh, and **Question 3:** I'm assuming that `printfn "%A"` is just for demonstration, right? But in a _real_ program, how would you consume those results when they are all of different types?

Comment: I don't think a DU is a solution, because as you state, the user might not be able to extend it. But generics may be an alternative.

Comment: The functions do two things in parallel, that doesn't seem to have anything to do with each other. I'd split each function into two functions, and then work on from there. Is there a one to one or a many to one or many to many relationship between the functions and the types? Do we have an XY problem here?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin yes. the print was just for demonstration. i removed it to avoid confusion

Comment: @BentTranberg i hope it's not an XY problem. i have added extra context

Comment: @BentTranberg i've also considered generics for the steps function. i seem to need runtime coercion. i've added my failed attempt. am i on the right track?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin i'm willing to accept that a type in funs doesn't match a type in states. if i have no other choice. so i may already be looking at it the wrong way by assuming it needs to be in a list

Comment: @FyodorSoikin in another language like c#, i would try to determine the type at runtime in and cast accordingly or i would make each state and function into a class. and have all these classes have the same base class

Comment: @FyodorSoikin i'm also considering allowing the user to create a record instead of a list of functions, and then using Reflection to iterate over then fields. besides looking static type, i would be concerned with performance in that case. in an ideal case, i would do that but then all statically type

Comment: You haven't answered my "question 3" yet.

Comment: **Question 4**: you state that in C# you would make both the state and the function into a class, with a common base class. Do you imply that in this solution there would be just one list of base classes, not two lists?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin **Question 4**: yes that's exactly what i'm considering. 1 list of classes. each class containing a state and a function

Comment: @FyodorSoikin **Question 3**: i want to take the float values from the results and add each to a different line as y-axis value of a graph. and save the states from the results to feed them back in for the next point. i want to repeat this several times

Answer (score 4):

When you find yourself asking "*but how to I make them all different types?*", the answer usually (though not always) ends up being "*you don't actually need to*." And to reveal the underlying structure of the problem, the two questions you have to ask are about inputs and outputs:

1. Where do the inputs ultimately come from? What is common about them? Since you aim to process them all in the same way, there must be *somehting* common. What is it? Can you encode it as a type?
   **In your case**, what's common about your inputs is that they are mathematical functions that you can "evaluate" to get out a number. So that should be their type.
2. How would the outputs be ultimately consumed? What is common about them? Again: since you aim to consume them all in the same way, there must be *something* common. Can you encode that as a type?
   **In your case**, there seem to be two kinds of outputs: (1) a number signifying the current value, and (2) a parameter used to compute the next value. The former is no problem: same type everywhere. But for the latter, the question applies: how is it ultimately used? You state that it's fed right back into the same function, which then again returns the value. So that should be its type: *a function that returns the next value*.

In case you missed the general approach in the details above, let me reiterate it: *How am I going to use these values? I am going to convert them to the same type **at some point**. So don't do it at some point, do it right away. Then all results are of the same type.*
Or, if it's too expensive to convert them right away, return a "lazy value" - i.e. a function that does the conversion.

So, applying the above to your case, here's how to refactor the solution:

1. Every function returns a pair of `float` + the same function again, which returns the next `float` + the same function again, which returns the next `float`, and so on.
   Of course, this would need a recursive type, which, if expressed naively, like `(float, unit -> (float, unit -> (float, unit -> ...)))`, would be an infinite type. But thankfully, we can still make a recursive type if we wrap it in a data constructor.
2. To make creation of such functions convenient, introduce a wrapper function that would encapsulate the recursion.
3. The "main" program would just keep calling the functions to get the next value at each iteration.

```
// ---- Lib.fs

type RecFn = RecFn of float * (unit -> RecFn)

let rec mkRecFn f state0 =
  let (curValue, nextState) = f state0
  RecFn (curValue, fun () -> mkRecFn f nextState )

type FState = {y:int; z:string}
let f x = mkRecFn <| fun (s: FState) -> (x + 1.0, {s with y = s.y+1})

type GState = {y:string}
let g x = mkRecFn <| fun (s:GState) -> (x*2.0, s)

type HState = {z:float}
let h = mkRecFn <| fun (s:HState) -> (0.0, s)

let steps = List.map (fun (RecFn (x, next)) -> next ())

// ---- Program.fs

type EState = {y:float}
let e = mkRecFn <| fun (s:EState) -> (1.0, {s with y=s.y/2.0})

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let funs : RecFn list =
        [ f 0.0 {FState.y=1; z=""}
        ; f 1.0 {FState.y=1; z=""}
        ; g 5.0 {GState.y=""}
        ; h {HState.z=2.0}
        ; e {EState.y=4.0}
        ]

    let results : RecFn list = steps funs
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

---

**NOTE**: there is now a single list `funs` instead of two lists, `funs` and `states`. I infer that this is ok, because you have stated in a comment that an equivalent C# implementation would have a single list of base objects.

Comment: that is a nice solution (really). but i apologize for failing to mention, that the state of these functions is not completely stuck in a closed loop (although conceptually it might be). the program needs the ability to stop running and resume at another time. the states are also used to do this. I'm assuming that the type `RecFn` can't be "saved" (serialized?) because it contains the function `unit -> RecFn`

Comment: This is exactly why I asked you how you would implement this in another language. Your proposed C# solution does not satisfy this condition either.

Comment: why do you think the C# solution doesn't satisfy this either? classes can be serialized

Comment: Are you talking about the built-in "free" serialization? Of so, that's the worst idea ever. You won't be able to deserialize after you've made some changes to the code. Just don't.

Comment: i'm talking about using JSON.NET

Comment: But if it's serialization that you had in mind - then sure, just add a serializing/deserializing functions to `RecFn` (and at this point probably better to make it a record). Also, I think I would separate the "construction" functions (i.e. either deserialization or creating a fresh instance) from the "instance" functions.